# Selenium Python - If element does not exist then do this, else

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm by no means an selenium expert, and thus I'm coming here humbly for help. After executing the python script below, I thought that if it failed in between prints, I could simply review the logs and see where the last print was. Unfortunately the script continues running until the end and prints everything whether or not it was successful. Here is what I have:

```
print("Attempting, map zoom 4x.")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
print("Zoom in 4x. Successful")
```

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
print("Attempting, map zoom 4x.")
if driver.find_element_by_xpath ...... exists,
then
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@class=\"leaflet-control-zoom-in\"]").click()
   print("Zoom in 4x. Successful")
else
   print("Element does not exist, it failed.")
```

How would I format this for python/selenium? Any help is appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You might try something like:

```
print("Attempting, map zoom 4x.")
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/xpath/to/your/element/here')
if elem.is_displayed():
    elem.click()
    print("Zoom in 4x. Successful")
else:
    print "Element is not visible"
```

Comment: Thanks qaduderino, I'm going to try this right now. Will report back with results.

Comment: It seems selenium hangs on driver.find....etc. Because it can't find the element to begin with. I've tried going directly to if statement.    if driver.find_element_by_xpath(.....).is_displayed(): which also fails.

Comment: print("Attempting to click-highlight 'missionname' in the mission list.")
        if self.is_element_present(By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), '123')]"):
                print("Element Found. Clicking Highlight.")
                driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), '123')]").click()
        else: self.fail("Click-highlight failed. Element not found?")

Comment: Sorry about formatting. Unable to figure out  `code`

Comment: hmm i've never tried is_element_present. i'll have to check that out